# How to change width of searchBar's scope?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard, uisearchbar

[Here is my picture when I run my program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0phd.png)

Xcode14.3.1
swift5.8.1

I have some child view controllers in my navigation controller. In one of these, a back button was automatically created, and I added a UIBarButtonItem on the right side of the navigation bar. I also programmatically created a search bar and set it as the title view.

However, when I display the scope bar of the search bar, it doesn't expand fully. The back button and the right barButtonItem seem to be interrupting it. Is it possible to make the search bar's scope expand to the full width?

```swift
import UIKit

class ResultSearchViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var rightBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
        searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
  

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Consider using UISearchController. It will make this easier.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I know that with UISearchController I can spread the scopeBar under the back button and right UIBarButtonItem to the full width of the screen. But at the same time,in this way, the searchbar is also placed under those buttons.I want the searchBar to be in line with them.Such fine tuning is not possible with the searchBar inside navigationBar, is it?